# Unable to Force a WSFC Cluster to Start Without a Quorum

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, clustering

I was testing a three node AlwaysOn availability group cluster.  SQL Server  is on Node 1 and I powered off Node 1 and Node 3 simultaneously.  The cluster lost its quorum and appear to be down.  I tried following "[Force a WSFC Cluster to Start Without a Quorum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/force-a-wsfc-cluster-to-start-without-a-quorum)", but I am unable to bring the cluster online.  It is stuck is "joining" state.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What can we do now?

[cluster log](https://expirebox.com/download/d179a0c97c3a4c71db1c83baf20a9080.html)

Initially the cluster service is down.  After executing the `Start-ClusterNode` command it goes into running state. I have tried restarting the cluster service and also restarting the node, but can't force quorum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the screenshot it shows the attempt to use `-FixQuorum` as part of the `Start-ClusterNode` cluster powershell commands, however the cluster log shows that quorum was not forced.

Your log shows the following:

> ```xml
> Creating cluster node <vector len='1'>
> <item>ClusSvc</item>
> </vector>
> ```

Which is just starting up the cluster service. The log is also missing the fact stating that on this node quorum was forced.

Here is an example of how a cluster log (WSFC 2016, like the one you posted) would look if you forced quorum on the node:

> ```xml
> Creating cluster node <vector len='2'>
> <item>ClusSvc</item>
> <item>/FixQuorum</item>
> </vector>
> ```

Additionally, you'd see another entry further down:

> ```
> [CS] FixQuorum mode is on
> ```

My suggestion is to log locally onto the server and try running the powershell command (after shutting down the cluster service if it's still running):

```
Start-ClusterNode -Node SQL2 -ForceQuorum
```

Then check the status about 15 seconds later with:

```
Get-ClusterNode -Node SQL2
```

Check to see what is the status and also check the cluster log to see if the `ForceQuorum` switch was properly passed.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Weird, I tried "net.exe start clussvc /forcequorum " instead of powershell and it worked.  Went back to trying powershell agian and weirdly powershell also works.  Thanks so much for the help.